# 2 or more Controls only 1 is considered Active

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I have 2 controls (`MyCtrl`) next to each other called `ctrlLeft` and `ctrlRight`.

Whenever one receives interaction it is considered active (by default the left one). I override OnDraw and customize the look of the active one a bit.

Currently I have a property `Active` and an event that I subscribe to from all `MyCtrl` in there I store a reference to the active one like this:

```
if (sender is MyCtrl) 
{
    ctrlActive = (sender as MyCtrl);
    ctrlLeft.Active = !(ctrlRight.Active = (ctrlActive == ctrlRight));
}
```

Either way I need to have `ctrlActive` as I use it for other things but what I am wondering is if this is the best way make them aware of each other?

Another option I thought of was to store references to every possible MyCtrl and then loop through em all and activate / deactivate the one that match sender just in case I in the future add a `ctrlMiddle`.

Are my thoughts wrong, is there better options to do this. For example, how does radiobuttons accomplish their similar functionality?

Edit: Thanks for all suggestions.

In my particular case I don't want/need a container as even if I have 3 `MyCtrl` only one can still be active and I don't want them to be "linked" 2 and 2 so I went with a `public static MyCtrl { get; set; }` that each control can check itself against and I can update it where I need to, which works in my case and rids me of the need to loop through a collection when using multiple `MyCtrl`.

Comment: @anchandra MyCtrl fires the event when either itself or one of it's subcontrols receives any interaction that qualifies to activate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods are sound. If you need multiple controls with only one being active consider a container (visual or otherwise) where the children supply an "activate" event TO the container and the children also subscribe to a "control activated" event FROM the container....if the child is not the control supplied by the containers "control activated" event..then paint it as not active otherwise paint as active.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage the activation by yourself, so I think that your method is good.

Answer (score 0):

I nearly had the same idea as Rusty. But i would make it a little more general.

Why not building a container control that contains two panels (like SplitContainer). The container control has a property Active of type `enum ActivePanel { First, Second }` and it can be switched from outside by a setter or automatically through a subscription of the container to the `Focus` event (or something similar).

With such an approach you also don't need a `ctrlMiddle` cause you can nest your container multiple times.

I think there are still some problems to solve by this idea, but it should give you a good direction.